# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI (with some results so far)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web-services, http

I have been given a c# code with simple API that returns successfully some results so far . For example :

With `/{controller}/companies`   i can get all companies .

Then I enriched the code in order to get a specific company based on its id and by calling :  `/{controller}/company/2` i get my results successfully.

the route/action for this , is :

```
[Route("Company/{id}", Name = "CompanyDetails")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getCompanyDetails(string id)
        { ... }
```

My final goal is to call an API that returns all the employees of a company based on its specific company id . For example:

```
/{controller}/company/2/employees
```

My code API consists of this :

```
[Route("Company/{id}/Employees", Name = "AllCompanyEmployees")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getCompanyEmployees(string companyId, List<int> employeesIds= default(List<int>)    
{
    // functionality ...
}
```

When i hit from postman i got the url matching error . I have tried almost everything that i 've read in similar posts but still nothing, no matching URL . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice in your working one - what is similar between `{id}` and your parameters? What is different about the one that **doesn't** work?

Comment: Change `companyId` to be `id`.

Comment: @Prometheus you show `{controller}` in the examples. clarify what that is and where it is in the route template. You show attribute routing but i suspect you are confusing convention-based and attribute routing and its expected behavior.

Comment: Well i am reffering to `[RoutePrefix("api/Data")]` above the controller class. More specific to `"/api/Data/"` but i dont think that this had to do with the current issue.

Comment: After replacing `companyId` with `id` it has actually returned something . An empty list. Not a proper result but at least there is a small progress. . something went wrong with a query i guess.  The current issue has been solved , so .. thanks !